# PostgreSQL include rows which contains a column null in the results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the following snippet to let you know the issue I have

[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=561af2da6a3328e27671442a63bb3ebf)

The query is used to get all the rows where I have the most recent `day`, `study_id` and `status` of a candidate from that table.

As you see from the example I'm getting only 2 rows but I should have more also including the rows having `site_id === null`.

I should have included also the row

```
('2020-01-02 00:00:00+00', 'TBX1', NULL, 'INCOMPLETE', 120, 100)
```

The final result I'm expecting

| study_id | site_id | status | day | day | study_id | site_id | status | total | current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TBX1 | SWE-1 | INCOMPLETE | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | TBX1 | SWE-1 | INCOMPLETE | 37 | 31 |
| TBX1 | SWE-2 | INCOMPLETE | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | TBX1 | SWE-2 | INCOMPLETE | 43 | 41 |
| TBX1 | null | INCOMPLETE | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | TBX1 | null | INCOMPLETE | 120 | 100 |

So, therefore, is included the row also wth site_id null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it "take last from each group" problem ?

```
select distinct on (study_id, site_id,status) 
  candidates.* from candidates
WHERE
        "study_id" in('TBX1')
        AND "status" in('INCOMPLETE')
order by study_id, site_id, status , day desc
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=efe5a15751c76bf019e088c5388dd567)

Comment: Why I couldn't think of using postgreSQL's power on this! Nice and I would mark this as the answer @Jakub.

Comment: I marked and very nice solution however I need to use count on the current column and I'm not sure in this last solution with distinct how would that work but in general is amazing yes

Comment: @Jakub, tell, what you want to count. You can always use subquery for counting or count() over (), but it depends on range of elements you want to count.

Comment: Yes I need to count the tola of the current column the sum of those numbers

Comment: @Jakub check last query in 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ea2882811af0798664f3f3d68f32bfe

I've added sum for total

Comment: I believe I didn't express myself well so my apologies I meant the sum(current) 
31 + 41 + 100 = 172

Comment: So in each row total sum of current ?
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=24d1806cd0d38b085db78bc2dc1e7447

Comment: no I just need one result which is a number the sum of current

Comment: In this case I propose https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4585b1798787da8d2fa02f9a0b3ffb2e

Comment: That perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly compare NULL. NULL = NULL check using = operator doesn't yield TRUE or FALSE but NULL.

Instead you can check if they are both NULL. ie:

```
SELECT
    --sum("current")
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        "study_id",
        "site_id",
        "status",
        max("day") AS "day"
    FROM
        "candidates"
    WHERE
        "study_id" in('TBX1')
        AND "status" in('INCOMPLETE')
    GROUP BY
        "study_id",
        "site_id",
        "status") AS "latest"
    INNER JOIN "candidates" ON "latest"."day" = "candidates"."day"
        AND "latest"."study_id" = "candidates"."study_id"
        AND ("latest"."site_id" = "candidates"."site_id" or 
            ("latest"."site_id" is null and "candidates"."site_id" is null))
        AND "latest"."status" = "candidates"."status";
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=085b83cf86f22e922df647333b538281)